# Size dependent files are not processed

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have two projects: one created using command

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-shared-app --shared
```

and second downloaded form https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=JY218G&_ga=2.2006136.871667362.1565873632-420835096.1565622419

The second project is an example how to use platform specific code (using for instance `*.android.css` files) - and it works for me as well.

What does not work in the case of the first project is using screen dependent files (like `*.minWH320.css`). It works fine in the second project. And I have no idea why.

Here you have pieces of output from `tns run android --bundle` command from both projects:

First project (not working; contains file `home.minWH800.css` next to the `home.css` file):

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 2668aed79c038fd7f109
Version: webpack 4.30.0
Time: 7309ms
Built at: 08/18/2019 9:09:21 PM
              Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
          bundle.js   25.1 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
       package.json  112 bytes           [emitted]  
         runtime.js   71.4 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]  
          vendor.js   13.2 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 447 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.tns.ts] 1.07 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.css] 19 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 64 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 982 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.tns.ts] 1.69 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.routes.ts] 243 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.html] 616 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.component.ts] 1.46 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/home/home.css] 56 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./main.tns.ts] 2.37 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 104 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 420 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
```

Second project (working):

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...
Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 4096MB memory limit

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 903a56cd63a36a028fbd
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 3712ms
Built at: 08/18/2019 9:12:15 PM
              Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
          bundle.js   30.8 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
       package.json  168 bytes           [emitted]  
         runtime.js   71.4 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]  
          vendor.js   3.58 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[./ sync ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$] . sync nonrecursive ^\.\/app\.(css|scss|less|sass)$ 174 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./ sync recursive (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$] . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)\.(xml|css|js|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$ 456 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app-root.xml] 312 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./app.css] 1.1 KiB {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./app.js] 487 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./app.ts] 2.2 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./home/home-page.common.css] 608 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./home/home-page.minWH200.css] 534 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./home/home-page.minWH320.css] 538 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./home/home-page.minWH800.css] 537 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./home/home-page.xml] 1020 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./observable-property-decorator.js] 697 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./observable-property-decorator.ts] 862 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
[./package.json] 168 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 172 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
```

Comment: It seems that it won't work. After some research I've finally found this: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/404

Comment: Use platform css plugin for platform / device specific CSS.